# Width not expanding?

Tags: css, html, css-position, line-breaks

I'm working on a map project and for some reason my tooltip's text width will continue to expand as wide as I want until I add a space to my text. If I add a space, it breaks to the next line; what is going on and how do I fix this? I'd like the text on one line without specifying a width so it can automatically set the width, how can I fix this?

In the example below, look at text "Baseball Fields" in the paragraph tag. If it reads "BaseballFields" it will stay on one line. But as soon as I add the space, it will line break.

```
<div style="width: 750px; height: 1221px; border: 0; padding: 0; margin-top: 10px; display: block; position:relative; background: url('http://www.thefirstacademy.org/filerequest/9701.jpg') no-repeat left top;">
    <style type="text/css">
        .triangle {
            position:absolute;
            bottom:-5px;
            left:40%;
            height:0;
            width:0;
            border-left:5px solid transparent;
            border-right:5px solid transparent;
            border-top:5px solid white;
        }
        .tooltip {
            color:#ef4c4c;
            background:#ffffff;
            padding:17 10;
            display:block;
            position:absolute;
            border-radius:5px;
            font:.8em 'MuseoSans-500','Museo Sans';
            top:-40px;
            box-shadow:0px 3px 3px #000;
            border:1px solid #000;
        }
    </style>

    <div class="marker" style="position:absolute;cursor:pointer;left:450px;top:75px;" id="baseball">
        <img src="http://www.thefirstacademy.org/filerequest/9702.png" alt="Location Marker" />
        <div class="tooltip" >
            <div class="triangle"></div>
            <p style="padding:0;margin:0;line-height:0;display:block;">Baseball Fields</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried `white-space: nowrap`?

Comment: THAT WAS IT! I will mark it solved after the time. I knew I was missing some CSS Snippet. What exactly is the purpose of that?

Comment: Eh, guess I can't mark your post as the solution when I marked it helpful =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a heads up: in addition to `white-space: nowrap;` it can be helpful to include `display: inline-block;` for browser compatibility purposes